# blockUI don't stop

Tags: angularjs, blockui

I added the [angular-block-ui module](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-block-ui) to my Angular project but it was not blocking the UI automatically during my ajax requests.

So, I tried to use it manually and it shows the block screen but it does not dismiss it.

So, I did a more simple test, just showing the block and trying to stop it after 2 seconds, and same issue. The screens gets blocked but it does not go away.

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

myApp.controller('LoginModalCtrl', function ($scope, blockUI) {

     $scope.login = function () {
        console.log("on submit");   

        blockUI.start();

        setTimeout(function(){
            //do what you need here
            blockUI.stop();
            console.log("finished")
        }, 2000);
    }

})
```

;

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it in a $scope.apply

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    blockUI.stop();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All this "blocking" consist of putting div on top of your page. Thats it.

Well it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/HjXcgQD7JghFjtsOAEo0?p=preview

You should use `$timeout`, not setTimeout.

Dont want to go into details, but it doesnt seem to be that smart library thow...

Comment: Thanks for they reply Petr. I am using angular-block-ui  which, yes, is similar to the jquery, but it was supposed to be fully automatic, so I would not have to worry to show/hide modal on every request.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$timeout`, not setTimeout.

```
'use strict';
myApp.controller('LoginModalCtrl', function ($scope, blockUI, $timeout) {

     $scope.login = function () {
        console.log("on submit");   

        blockUI.start();

        $timeout(function(){
            //do what you need here
            blockUI.stop();
            console.log("finished")
        }, 2000);
    }

})
```